# Quartz and Spring: dynamic scheduling

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a web service which makes a **dynamic scheduling** of a certain job. The job is a Java class which extends the Quartz Job interface

```
public class StartJob implements Job {
    private String jobId;
    private DAO dao;

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        JobDataMap dataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap();

        //some logic here
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

I also expose an API which receives a jobId a cron expression and schedules a new StartJob that will have the received id. Here is my **Spring configuration**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "persistence.dao" })
@ImportResource({"spring-quartz-context.xml"})
public class BeanConfig {
    //wired from the xml
    @Autowired JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory;
    @Autowired CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactory;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean bean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        bean.setApplicationContextSchedulerContextKey("applicationContext");
        bean.setSchedulerName("MyScheduler");
        Map<String, Object> schedulerContextAsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        bean.setSchedulerContextAsMap(schedulerContextAsMap);
        // quartzproperties not reported
        bean.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());

        return bean;
    }

    //other bean definitions

}
```

and the spring-quartz-config.xml

```
<bean name="complexJobDetail"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="jobs.StartJob" />
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="complexJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * ? * SAT-SUN" />
</bean>
```

**What I want to do** is something like (pseudocode)

```
JobDetail job = jobDetailFactory.getObject();
job.setName(aGeneratedUUID);
CronTrigger trigger = cronTriggerFactory.getObject();
trigger.setCronExpression(aDynamicCronExpression);

scheduler.schedule(job, trigger);
```

but the problem is that I'm not able to change the job name and so, **only the first job is scheduled**. This first job uses as a name the JobDetailFactoryBean's name (complexJobDetail).

What am i missing here? Is this configuration correct? And are jobs and triggers retrieved from the factories new instances of the same class or they are the same class instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that I was not calling the method `afterPropertiesSet()`. So

```
jobDetailFactory.setName(generatedUUID);
jobDetailFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
JobDetail job = jobDetailFactory.getObject();
```

works, the job created has the new name.